# ¿cómo separar la Hora y Fecha y darle formato al exportar Excel? Usando Laravel Maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

Tengo el siguiente código, y un campo `created_at` autodefinido por Laravel con `timeStamp()`, requiero que cuando vaya a exportar a excel pueda separar la fecha y la hora para poner cada una en una celda y darle formato de ser posible.

Mi controlador:

```
public function excel()
{
    return Excel::download(new VisitsExport, 'visits.xlsx');
}
```

Mi Export:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Visit;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class VisitsExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return Visit::all();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Id',
            'Id Empresa',
            'Nombre',
            'Apellido',
            'Sexo',
            'CUIT',
            'Fecha de Nacimiento',
            'Fecha y hora de la visita',
        ];
    }
}
```

En el código anterior guardo la fecha y hora en el formato de `Mysql` en una sola celda. `'Fecha y hora de la visita'`, me gustaria que sean: `'Fecha de la visita'` y `'Hora de la visita'`

También probé convirtiendo la colección en un array y lo recibo en el Export, pero no se como exportarlo a excel como deseo.

```
public function excel()
{
    $visits = Visit::all()->toArray();
    return Excel::download(new VisitsExport($visits), 'visits.xlsx');
}
```

Y lo recibo así:

```
public function __construct(array $visits)
{
    $this->visits = $visits;
}

public function query()
{
    $this->visits; // Aquí lo recibo pero no sé como guardar la información para exportarla
}
```

Así recibo la información en `query()` con `dd($this->visits);`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y por qué en la query que haces no los separas? Veo que haces `Visit::all()`, simplemente tendrías que hacer `Visit::selectRaw('DATE(...), TIME(...)')->get()` etc.

Comment: Disculpa  actualicé la p´regunta, no la había tomado.

Comment: Eso es lo que no sabía como hacer, dejame intentar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví con la respuesta de L. Flor `Visit::selectRaw('DATE(...), TIME(...)')->get()` muchas gracias!